# Issue with Regex lookahead

Tags: regex, search, replace, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to use a regular expression which includes a lookahead, and I'm not able to get it to work correctly (as I expect).

My results seem to be inconsistent, so I suspect this is a problem with the program I'm using, but I can't pin it down, and it's possible I'm just doing something wrong.

I have a file loaded that contains a hex image something like this:

```
0000  ff ff 06 00 07 00 54 65 78 74 31 00 00 00 00 00  ÿÿ....Text1.....
0010  54 65 78 74 3f 00 00 00 00 54 65 78 74 33 01 10  Text?....Text3..
0020  44 3a 50 61 74 68 5c 46 69 6c 65 2e 65 78 74 00  D:Path\File.ext.
```

The part before and after "Text?" is variable length and variable content so a non-standard, "hybrid" representation might look like this:

```
0000  ff ff 06 00 07 00  T  e  x  t  1 00 00 00 00 00 
0010  ... T  e  x  t  ? 00 ... 00 T  e  x  t  3 01 10
0020   D  :  P  a  t  h  \  F  i  l  e  .  e  x  t 00
```

I have the cursor positioned at offset 0000, and I'm searching (Regular expression) for this:

```
(\xff\xff.{4}Text1\x00.{19,39}\x00)(?=Text3\x01.{1})
  or
\xff\xff.{4}Text1\x00.{19,39}\x00(?=Text3\x01.)
```

And trying to replace it with this:

```
\x01\x02\x03\x04
```

I expect it to end up like this (with the cursor positioned on the "T" in "Text3"):

```
0000  01 02 03 04 54 65 78 74 33 01 10 44 3a 50 61 74  ....Text3..D:Pat
0010  68 5c 46 69 6c 65 2e 65 78 74 00                 h\File.ext.
```

Mostly, I get "Pattern not found" or something similar, but sometimes the cursor position changes (I think usually positioned to the "T" in "Text3"), as though a replacement had been made, but nothing before the "Text3" is changed, and the replacement data `"\x01\x02\x03\x04"` is ignored.

I've tried various revisions of the search expression and it seems to work if I change the lookahead into a normal capture group like this:

```
Search:  (\xff\xff.{4}Text1\x00.{19,39}\x00)(Text3\x01.)
Replace: \x01\x02\x03\x04$2
```

I end up with this (with the cursor positioned on the "D" in "D:Path"):

```
0000  01 02 03 04 54 65 78 74 33 01 10 44 3a 50 61 74  ....Text3..D:Pat
0010  68 5c 46 69 6c 65 2e 65 78 74 00                 h\File.ext.
```

However, if I try this:

```
Search:  (\xff\xff.{4}Text1\x00.{29}\x00)(?=Text3\x01.{1})
Replace: \x01\x02\x03\x04
```

I again expect this (with the cursor positioned on the "T" in "Text3"):

```
0000  01 02 03 04 54 65 78 74 33 01 10 44 3a 50 61 74  ....Text3..D:Pat
0010  68 5c 46 69 6c 65 2e 65 78 74 00                 h\File.ext.
```

but I end up with this (with the cursor positioned on the "D" in "D:Path"):

```
0000  01 02 03 04 44 3a 50 61 74 68 5c 46 69 6c 65 2e  ....D:Path\File.
0010  65 78 74 00                                      ext.
```

And further, if I try the same search, with "$2" added to the end of the replacement (which doesn't make sense since the second group is non-capturing), like this:

```
Search:  (\xff\xff.{4}Text1\x00.{29}\x00)(?=Text3\x01.)
Replace: \x01\x02\x03\x04$2
```

I get close to what I originally wanted (except the cursor is positioned on the "D" in "D:Path"), but not what I expect (I expect an error):

```
0000  01 02 03 04 54 65 78 74 33 01 10 44 3a 50 61 74  ....Text3..D:Pat
0010  68 5c 46 69 6c 65 2e 65 78 74 00                 h\File.ext.
```

So, it appears to have trouble using a lookahead following a variable length expression (outside of the lookahead). And, using a lookahead following a fixed length expression, it seems to be treating the lookahead as a normal capture group.

I haven't mentioned the name of the program because I wanted to first find out if I am understanding things correctly and my expectations are correct, and then I wanted to see if a software update (not free) would fix this.

Comment: What happens if you use a non-capturing group (or no group at all) around the part you're replacing?  Also, can you perform a similar operation on normal text, rather than binary?

Comment: @AlanMoore - I haven't tried a non-capturing group, but I've tried a "normal" capture-group ["(RE)"], and I've tried with "no group at all". Both seem to always work. The more I play with this, the more I am convinced the software is misbehaving. I'm mostly trying to find out if my assumptions/expectations are largely correct. If so, then the software is definitely misbehaving.

Comment: I'd say your expectations are correct.  It looks broken to me.

Comment: Are you able to recreate this work normal text? a) it might help you figure out what's going on and b) I (and possibly others) find hex code hard to read and understand, so more people would be able to help out?